What survey questions might you ask if you want to uncover why they might not be using / doing something?
PMs want me to survey why users exposed to three different types of orders might not take a specific type of order and, simultaneously, why some they might choose that specific type of order. What questions would be most suitable to get to the root cause of the matter? They have already looked into the data and were still confused as to why.

In your context, you want to know why your users make decisions. Based on the three different types of orders, I suggest you find factors that affect their decision-making and start questioning them from your users' perspective. Since I don't know what affects it, I will give you an example of a general reason.

Personal priorities

What factors did you use to decide between each option?


Benefits and features

What features made you choose this option over the other?


Situation Context

How did your feelings at the time affect the choice you've made?



